# communicate between 2 classes in android

Tags: java, android, subclass

ok I have 2 classes

**an activity class** and another class which extended from `maps.Overlay`. so the second class cannot be extended from first class because it already extended.

**my second class** gets the geo coordinates from user touch location on a map. what I want to do is show a window(not alert box) to proceed. In order to do that, I have to alert the activity class somehow. because I can't call `setContentView(R.layout.insertwin)`; in my second class. somehow it must need to call in the activity class. how would I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do your own listener interface in the `View` subclass and subscribe to this listener int the `Activity` subclass after calling `setContentView()`. So you'll be able to notify your activity about any events you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement singleton to do such things